# remove images which don't have the class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove the images which don't have the class.

html

```
<div id="slider">
<img class="" />
<img class="" />
<img class="img1" />
<img class="img2" />
<img class=" " />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
if(!$('#slider img').class()){
$('#slider img').remove(); // but I'm stucked at this line
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you can do is remove images whose class attribute value does not begin with `img`

```
$('#slider img:not([class^=img])').remove();
```

but a more correct solution will be

```
$('#slider img').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.className).length === 0
}).remove();
```

Comment: `$.trim(this.className).length === 0`, not `> 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slider img").each(function(i){
         if($(this).class=""){
             //do whatever
         }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Select everything, then filter out the things you don't want...

```
$("#slider img")
.filter(function(i) { return $(this).attr("class") == ""; })
.remove();
```